# Simple jQuery scroller - how to make it infinite?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Hey guys here is my code:

```
function scroll(obj) {
  $(obj).animate({top:'-'+$('li:nth-child(1)', obj)
        .outerHeight(true)}, 15000, 'linear', function(){
            $(obj).css({top:0});scroll(obj);
        });
}
```

Just wondering how I could make it infinite (either keep looping or keep going from top to bottom) instead of just jumping back to the top.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
function scrollDown(obj){
    obj.animate({top:'-'+$('li:nth-child(1)', obj).outerHeight(true)}, 15000, 'linear', function(){scrollUp($(this));});
}

function scrollUp(obj){
    obj.animate({top:0)}, 15000, 'linear', function(){scrollDown($(this));});
}

scrollDown($("#myObject"));
```

Comment: @user1294381 - I suggest you show appreciation then, by upvoting and/or accepting this answer.